# Tomcat 7 deployed Web Application 404 Status

Tags: apache, tomcat, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

I have deployed a web application to Tomcat 7.0.47 however I see a 404 status.
I can access Tomcat homepage and Tomcat Application Manager without issues.

[image: Tomcat Web Application Manager]

[image: HTTP Status 404]

Here are the log files:
**catalina.2016-07-13**

```
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;F:\MATLAB\R2014a\runtime\win64;F:\MATLAB\R2014a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;.
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 514 ms
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\cs144.war
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\docs
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\examples
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\host-manager
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manager
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\ROOT
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\Struts2Example
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\zurmo
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1435 ms
```

**localhost.2016-07-13**

```
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 13, 2016 8:51:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@7a1f7380')
```

**localhost_access_log.2016-07-13**

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [13/Jul/2016:08:53:14 +0430] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=210FE5528CB1E9D58F23E5A11655B102 HTTP/1.1" 403 3287
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Jul/2016:08:53:14 +0430] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Jul/2016:08:53:18 +0430] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - admin [13/Jul/2016:08:53:18 +0430] "GET /manager/html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7D8792E571C6ABBD8D35351293AF54B8 HTTP/1.1" 200 20949
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Jul/2016:08:53:33 +0430] "GET /cs144/ HTTP/1.1" 404 963
```

**manager.2016-07-13**

```
Jul 13, 2016 8:53:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
Jul 13, 2016 8:53:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
Jul 13, 2016 8:53:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

Comment: How is the `cs144` webapp configured? Does it contain `index.jsp` or `index.html` file? Or is there a servlet configured to handle the `/` request?

Comment: Thanks for your response, It contains results.jsp, however I don't know how to configure a servlet to handle the / request. Can you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Use the `<welcome-file>` facility in `web.xml`. Before trying that, go ahead and see if a request to `/cs144/results.jsp` succeeds. If so, all you need is a `<welcome-file>` to re-route requests for `/` to `/results.jsp`.

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherSchultz! I tried `/cs144/results.jsp` and it worked. I still need to figure out how to use `<welcome-file>` to re-route requests for `/` to `/results.jsp`as I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the  facility in `web.xml`.

The servlet spec provides a facility for applications to indicate what file(s) should be used when the client doesn't specify one in a path -- e.g. `GET /directory/`. You can specify as many files as you want, and the first one found will be used. So you could have e.g. `index.html` in there as well as anything else you might want. The default list is (in order):

- `index.html`
- `index.htm`
- `index.jsp`

If you specify a `<welcome-file-list>` in your `web.xml`, you'll override the default. So, if you want to be able to fall-back to the original list, you'll need to specify all of the options.

Example:

`web.xml`

```
...
...
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>results.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
...
...
```

The `web.xml` file should be in your application's `WEB-INF/web.xml`, and probably already exists. Make sure you follow the [schema](http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd) and put it in the right place.